# How to Align form to the center in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with aligning the forms and buttons to the center, here is my code:

```
<body>
<h1 style="font-family:Comic Sans Ms;text-align:center;font-size:50pt;color:#ff00ba;">
 You need to login :) </h1>     

<form style="font-family:Comic Sans Ms; align:center;">
 Username<br>
<input type="text" name="userid"/><br>
 Password<br>
<input type="password" name="pswrd"/>
<br><br>
<input style="font-family:Comic Sans Ms;" type="button" onclick="check(form)" value="Login"/>
<input style="font-family:Comic Sans Ms;" type="reset" value="Cancel"/>
</form>
........
```

You can see that I have put "align:center" in the form style, but it does not work, the form and button are still in the left of the webpage, actually, I tried div and it worked. however, how about if I do not use div and I just want to use my current format to style the alignment, is there any way to get it centered? Cheers

Answer (score 4):

Use text-align:center;

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mLrwq1w6/)

```
<body>
<h1 style="font-family:Comic Sans Ms;text-align:center;font-size:50pt;color:#ff00ba;">
 You need to login :) </h1>     

<form style="font-family:Comic Sans Ms; text-align: center;">
 Username<br>
<input type="text" name="userid"/><br>
 Password<br>
<input type="password" name="pswrd"/>
<br><br>
<input style="font-family:Comic Sans Ms;" type="button" onclick="check(form)" value="Login"/>
<input style="font-family:Comic Sans Ms;" type="reset" value="Cancel"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Hi Jokim, thanks for reply, it is working,  if I write like this: <input style="text-align:center;" type="text" name="userid"/><br> I move the aligh center to input section, it is not working, do you know why?

Answer (score 1):

The CSS "align: center;" property is wrong. "**text-align: center;**" may be what you are looking for.

Although it's named "text-align", it affects how content, not necessarily text, gets aligned inside the element in which it's applied. For example, you can align other HTML elements or images inside a form:

```
<form style="width:500px;text-align:center"> <!--This will align the 'input' on the center of the 'form'.-->
    <input type="text" style="text-align:center"> <!--This will align the text to the center of the 'input'.-->
</form>
```

Comment: Hi Chimos, thanks for reply, it is working, but I tried to write like this:  <input style="text-align:center;" type="text" name="userid"/><br> I move the aligh center to input section, but it is not working again, why is that

Comment: It affects how things get aligned inside the element where you are applying it. If you want to center the input itself, you should apply "text-align:center" to its container (in your code "form")

Answer (score 0):

Try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hxhL6v6u/2/)**

**CSS:**

```
form, h1{
    clear:both;
    max-width:80%;
    margin:0 auto;
    display:block;
    font-family:Comic Sans Ms;
    text-align:center;
}
```